# Play a single frame in a video for multiple seconds, as if video is paused on one frame

Tags: davinci-resolve

How can you slice a video and then play up to the the frame at the slice for multiple seconds, then resume the video after the slice? An example would be a 5 second video, sliced at 2.5 seconds, showing the frame at 2.5 for the next 5 seconds, then resuming to show the remaining 2.5 making it a total of 10 seconds long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a freeze frame, under the retime controls of the clip. It’s command/control-R with the clip selected to see the retime menu.